# Is the set of real numbers not a subset of the set of whole numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this proposition true?

$\mathbb R \nsubseteq \mathbb N $

It may seem trivial, but I want to be sure. Also would the simple "not subset" operator without the "not equal" part be more suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We write $A\subseteq B$ if every $a$ which is an element of $A$ is an element of $B$. If $A\subseteq B$ and $A\neq B$ we write $A\subsetneq B$ (and sometimes $A\subset B$, although that may denote possible equality as well).

If we write $A\nsubseteq B$ then we mean that $A$ is not a subset of $B$. This means that there exists some $a\in A$ such that $a\notin B$.

Now, is $\Bbb{R\subseteq N}$ or not?

Comment: It is not. So my proposition is true. Correct? As a side note the \nsubset Mathjax shortcode does not work on this Web site.

Comment: Yeah, your proposition is true. As a side note, $\subset$ and its negation shouldn't be used.

Comment: I understand the difference, but when you say "shouldn't be used", do you mean it could cause ambiguous interpretation?

Comment: Yes, that is why.